# Spark MLib Decision Trees: Probability of labels by features?

Tags: python, apache-spark, decision-tree, data-science

I could manage to display total probabilities of my `labels`, for example after displaying my decision tree, I have a table :

```
Total Predictions :
    65% impressions
    30% clicks
    5%  conversions
```

But my issue is to find probabilities (or to count) by `features` (by node), for example :

```
if feature1 > 5
   if feature2 < 10
      Predict Impressions
      samples : 30 Impressions
   else feature2 >= 10
      Predict Clicks
      samples : 5 Clicks
```

`Scikit` does it automatically , I am trying to find a way to do it with `Spark`

Comment: Can you use Scala?

Comment: @DanieldePaula , Yes it does not matter.

Comment: I have an idea with Scala. I will share with you when I have some time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note: the following solution is for Scala only. I didn't find a way to do it in Python.*

Assuming you just want a visual representation of the tree as in your example, maybe one option is to adapt the method `subtreeToString` present in the [`Node.scala`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/tree/model/Node.scala) code on Spark's GitHub to include the probabilities at each node split, like in the following snippet:

```scala
def subtreeToString(rootNode: Node, indentFactor: Int = 0): String = {
  def splitToString(split: Split, left: Boolean): String = {
    split.featureType match {
      case Continuous => if (left) {
        s"(feature ${split.feature} <= ${split.threshold})"
      } else {
        s"(feature ${split.feature} > ${split.threshold})"
      }
      case Categorical => if (left) {
        s"(feature ${split.feature} in ${split.categories.mkString("{", ",", "}")})"
      } else {
        s"(feature ${split.feature} not in ${split.categories.mkString("{", ",", "}")})"
      }
    }
  }
  val prefix: String = " " * indentFactor
  if (rootNode.isLeaf) {
    prefix + s"Predict: ${rootNode.predict.predict} \n"
  } else {
    val prob = rootNode.predict.prob*100D
    prefix + s"If ${splitToString(rootNode.split.get, left = true)} " + f"(Prob: $prob%04.2f %%)" + "\n" +
      subtreeToString(rootNode.leftNode.get, indentFactor + 1) +
      prefix + s"Else ${splitToString(rootNode.split.get, left = false)} " + f"(Prob: ${100-prob}%04.2f %%)" + "\n" +
      subtreeToString(rootNode.rightNode.get, indentFactor + 1)
  }
}
```

I've tested it on a model I run on the [Iris dataset](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/multiclass.html#iris), and I've got the following result:

```
scala> println(subtreeToString(model.topNode))

If (feature 2 <= -0.762712) (Prob: 35.35 %)
 Predict: 1.0
Else (feature 2 > -0.762712) (Prob: 64.65 %)
 If (feature 3 <= 0.333333) (Prob: 52.24 %)
  If (feature 0 <= -0.666667) (Prob: 92.11 %)
   Predict: 3.0
  Else (feature 0 > -0.666667) (Prob: 7.89 %)
   If (feature 2 <= 0.322034) (Prob: 94.59 %)
    Predict: 2.0
   Else (feature 2 > 0.322034) (Prob: 5.41 %)
    If (feature 3 <= 0.166667) (Prob: 50.00 %)
     Predict: 3.0
    Else (feature 3 > 0.166667) (Prob: 50.00 %)
     Predict: 2.0
 Else (feature 3 > 0.333333) (Prob: 47.76 %)
  Predict: 3.0
```

A similar approach could be used for creating a tree structure with this information. The main difference would be to store the printed information (`split.feature`, `split.threshold`, `predict.prob`, and so on) as vals and use them to build the structure.

Comment: This is exactly what I want !

Comment: Hey guys, any chance either of you have a solution like this using the DataFrame API? See this question for some rep!: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40558567/how-to-view-random-forest-statistics-in-spark-scala