# Statistics for Spark mllib DecisionTree

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, decision-tree, apache-spark-mllib

After learning a mllib DecisionTree model (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-decision-tree.html) how do I calculate node statistics, such as support (how many samples match this subtree) and how many samples per label match this subtree?

If it's easier I am also happy to take any other tool than Spark to take the debug string and calculate those statistics. Example of the debug string:

```
DecisionTreeModel classifier of depth 20 with 20031 nodes
  If (feature 0 <= -35.0)
   If (feature 24 <= 176.0)
    If (feature 0 <= -200.0)
     If (feature 29 <= 109.0)
      If (feature 6 <= -156.0)
       If (feature 9 <= 0.0)
        If (feature 20 <= -116.0)
         If (feature 16 <= 203.0)
          If (feature 11 <= 163.0)
           If (feature 5 <= 384.0)
            If (feature 15 <= 325.0)
             If (feature 13 <= -248.0)
              If (feature 20 <= -146.0)
               Predict: 0.0
              Else (feature 20 > -146.0)
               If (feature 19 <= -58.0)
                Predict: 6.0
               Else (feature 19 > -58.0)
                Predict: 0.0
             Else (feature 13 > -248.0)
              If (feature 9 <= -26.0)
               Predict: 0.0
              Else (feature 9 > -26.0)
               If (feature 10 <= 218.0)
...
```

I am using mllib because of out-of-core learning, which I need because the data does not fit into memory. If you have better alternatives than mllib I am happy to give them a try.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/) as the algorithm to create my model,and integrating with Spark Context to produce such an output :

```
if ( device_type_id <= 1 )
    39 Clicks - 0.61%
    2135 Conversions - 33.32% 
else ( device_type_id > 1 )
    if ( country_id <= 216 )
        1097 Clicks - 17.12%
    else ( country_id > 216 )
        if ( browser_id <= 2 )
            296 Clicks - 4.62%
        else ( browser_id > 2 )
            if ( browser_id <= 4 )
                if ( browser_id <= 3 )
                    if ( operating_system_id <= 2 )
                        262 Clicks - 4.09%
```

Here is the code I use to display such a tree :

```
def get_code(count_df, tree, feature_names, target_names, spacer_base="    "):
    left      = tree.tree_.children_left
    right     = tree.tree_.children_right
    threshold = tree.tree_.threshold
    features  = [feature_names[i] for i in tree.tree_.feature]
    value = tree.tree_.value
    temp_list = []
    res_count = count_df
    def recurse(res_count, temp_list, left, right, threshold, features, node, depth):
        spacer = spacer_base * depth
        if (threshold[node] != -2):
            temp_list.append("if ( " + features[node] + " <= " + \
                str(int(round(threshold[node] - 1))) + " )")
            if left[node] != -1:
                    recurse (res_count, temp_list, left, right, threshold, features, left[node], depth+1)
            temp_list.append("else ( " + features[node] + " > " + \
                str(int(round(threshold[node] - 1))) + " )")
            if right[node] != -1:
                    recurse (res_count, temp_list, left, right, threshold, features, right[node], depth+1)

        else:
            target = value[node]
            for i, v in zip(np.nonzero(target)[1], target[np.nonzero(target)]):
                target_name = target_names[i]
                target_count = int(v)
                temp_list.append(str(target_count) +" "+ str(target_name) + " - " + str(round((target_count / res_count), 4) * 100)+ "%")

    recurse(res_count, temp_list, left, right, threshold, features, 0, 0)
    return temp_list
```

Otherwise, please refer to the answer provided in my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37129602/spark-mlib-decision-trees-probability-of-labels-by-features) , however it is written in `Scala`, changing the way `Spark` generate the decision tree.

Comment: I can't use sklearn decision trees because they don't support online/out of core training. But the output you are getting looks like it could be what I want (you have two labels, clicks and conversions is that right?). Can you provide some code to get this output? Can I also get it from a spark mllib model?