# Using CategoricalFeaturesInfo with DecisionTreeClassifier method in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, decision-tree, apache-spark-ml

I have to use this code:

```scala
val dt = new DecisionTreeClassifier().setLabelCol("indexedLabel").setFeaturesCol("indexedFeatures").setImpurity(impurity).setMaxBins(maxBins).setMaxDepth(maxDepth);
```

I need to add categorical features information so that the decision tree doesn't treat the `indexedCategoricalFeatures` as numerical. I have this map:

```scala
val categoricalFeaturesInfo = Map(143 -> 126, 144 -> 5, 145 -> 216, 146 -> 100, 147 -> 14, 148 -> 8, 149 -> 19, 150 -> 7);
```

However it only works with `DecisionTree.trainClassifier` method. I can't use this method because it accepts different arguments than the one I have... I would really want to be able to use the `DecisionTreeClassifie`r with categorical features treated properly.

Thank your for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing two different APIs which take different approach to categorical data:

- `RDD` based `o.a.s.mllib` which provides required metadata by passing `categoricalFeaturesInfo` map.
- `Dataset` (`DataFrame`) `o.a.s.ml` which is using column metadata to determine variable types. If you correctly use `ML` transformers to create features this should be handled automatically for you, otherwise you'll have to [provide metadata manually](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35305154/1560062).

Comment: Thank you. However, I don't see which ML transformer would handle automatically this for me. If you can point me out to it I will accept your response and +1 it as due!

Comment: This solely depends on your pipeline. Pretty much every ML transformer has specific semantics and will set some type of metadata on the schema. You'll just have to be aware of that and keep in mind that pipeline should reflect semantics of your data. Details are far to broad for SO IMHO. You can find some information [here](https://github.com/awesome-spark/spark-gotchas/blob/master/06_data_preparation.md) (disclaimer: I am co-author) but this is only a tip of the iceberg.

Comment: Sorry to be asking this here, but do you have idea how to display the decision tree with string categories instead of indexed categories? Thank you.

Comment: If you're looking for out-of-the box AFAIK there is none at this moment. You can check http://stackoverflow.com/a/37311078/1560062 for example how to traverse tree and and adjust it with meta.