# How to view Random Forest statistics in Spark (scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have a RandomForestClassifierModel in Spark. Using .toDebugString() outputs the following

```
Tree 0 (weight 1.0):
  If (feature 0 in {1.0,2.0,3.0})
   If (feature 3 in {2.0,3.0})
    If (feature 8 <= 55.3) 
.
.
  Else (feature 0 not in {1.0,2.0,3.0})
.
.
Tree 1 (weight 1.0):
.
.
...etc
```

I'd like to view the actual data as it goes through the model, something like

```
Tree 0 (weight 1.0):
  If (feature 0 in {1.0,2.0,3.0}) 60%
   If (feature 3 in {2.0,3.0}) 57%
    If (feature 8 <= 55.3) 22%
.
.
  Else (feature 0 not in {1.0,2.0,3.0}) 40%
.
.
Tree 1 (weight 1.0):
.
...etc
```

By seeing the probability of labels in each node, I can see which paths are most likely to be followed in the trees by the data (thousands of records), which would be really good insight!

I found an awesome answer here: [Spark MLib Decision Trees: Probability of labels by features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37129602/spark-mlib-decision-trees-probability-of-labels-by-features/37311078#37311078)

Unfortunately the method in the answer uses the MLlib API, and after lots of trying, I have failed to replicate it using the DataFrame API, which has different implementations of the classes Node and Split :(

Comment: Maybe you can try to adapt the original answer by looking at the code for the ml package: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.0/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/tree/Node.scala

Comment: I took a look into the code. I'm not sure it's possible (at least not with the same strategy as the other answer), because the ratio of splits in each node is inside an "impurityStats" attribute, which is private to the ml package. Maybe it can be possible to create this attribute with ImpurityCalculator using the visible attributes of Node, but I can't find a way.

Comment: @DanieldePaula Thank you for looking into that. I'd rather not refactor my whole pipeline to use mllib. I'll try to find a way using your last suggestion. So far I can get every tree of the forest in an array. I'd like to do this using the API without having to re-write a whole lot of classes. If you happen to come up with any other solutions please let me know!

Comment: looking a bit further I found out that there is an open ticket for it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3727 and it has not yet been done. So, apparently, there is no support for it yet in the ml package.

Answer (score 1):

One way I found useful yesterday was I could use spark.read.parquet() function to read the output from the model/data file. This way all information about a certain node could be retrieved as a whole dataframe.

```
`val modelPath = "some/path/to/your/model"
val dataPath = modelPath + "/data"    
val nodeData: DataFrame = spark.read.parquet(dataPath)
nodeData.show(500,false)
nodeData.printSchema()`
```

Then you can rebuild the tree with information. Hope it helps.