# Spark (Scala): How to turn an Array[Row] into either a DataSet[Row] or a DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have an Array[Row] and I want to turn it into either a `Dataset[Row]` or `DataFrame`.

How did I come up with an Array of Rows?

Well, I was trying to clear nulls from my dataset:

- **without** having to filter EACH column (I have a lot) and..
- **without** using the `.na.drop()` function from `DataFrameNaFunctions` because it fails to detect when a cell actually has the string `"null"`.

So, I came up with the following line to filter out `null` in all columns.

```scala
val outDF = inputDF.columns.flatMap { col => inputDF.filter(col + "!='' AND " + col + "!='null'").collect() }
```

Problem is, outDF is an `Array[Row]`, hence the question! Any ideas welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm posting the answer as per my comment.

```
df.na.drop(df.columns).where("'null' not in ("+df.columns.mkString(",")+")")
```

Comment: This looks like it only drops `'null'` and not actual `null`. Is this the desired behavior?

Comment: `na.drop(df.columns)` drops `null`

Comment: The where part can be extracted from the string: `.where(df.columns.map(c => col(c) !== "null").reduce(_ and _))`

Comment: @DanieldePaula your answer works even better, I'm using that (with =!= instead of !==). You seem to really have a handle on Spark, any chance you can look at my random forest question? its similar to one you already answered, but I haven't been able to solve it yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40558567/how-to-view-random-forest-statistics-in-spark-scala

Answer (score 3):

This is what your code would do if it worked:

```
inputDF.columns.map {
  col => inputDF.filter((inputDF(col) =!= "") and (inputDF(col) =!= "null"))
}.reduce(_ union _)
```

and something like this:

```
inputDF.where(inputDF.columns.map {
  col => (inputDF(col) =!= "") and (inputDF(col) =!= "null")
}.foldLeft(lit(true))(_ and _))
```

is what you want.

Note that the first solution creates non-exclusive subsets so with data like this:

```
val inputDF = Seq(("1", "a"), ("2", ""), ("null", "")).toDF
```

the result would be:

```
+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
|  1|  a|
|  2|   |
|  1|  a|
+---+---+
```

For the solution I believe to be correct:

```
+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
|  1|  a|
+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

This was answered by using the following code, base on Mr Srinivas's comment:

```
//First drop all typical nulls
val prelimDF = inputDF.na.drop()

//Then drops all columns actually saying 'null'
val finalDF = prelimDF.na.drop(prelimDF.columns).where("'null' not in ("+prelimDF.columns.mkString(",")+")")
```

Cheers!